# Theorems linking the Lie group of the circle and circle homeomorphisms

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, lie-groups, circles

This is more a question for literature: I'm currently working on my masters thesis about the classification of maps on $\mathbb{S}^1$. I recently started reading about the interpretation of $\mathbb{S}^1$ as a Lie group and found it to be really interesting. I found a few sources that examine the structure of the group of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms which seem to form kind of a Lie group (?). I'm wondering now if there is a central theorem and proof that I could present in my thesis. For homeomorphisms in general there's the Poincaré classification and for diffeomorphisms there's Denjoy's theorem. However I was unable to find some theorem of that kind that links homeomorphisms of the circle to Lie groups or circle maps to groups in general. Maybe someone knows about something like that, thanks!

Comment: At the very minimum, Lie groups are a special subclass of topological groups. The group of homeomorphisms $\text{Homeo}(\mathbb S^1)$ is also a topological group, using the compact open topology, and the Lie group structure on $\mathbb S^1$ makes it a topological subgroup of $\text{Homeo}(\mathbb S^1)$.

Comment: You might be interested in learning about the "rotation number" of a homeomorphism of a circle, or maybe you already know about this. Eventually you might like to learn about "Denjoy's theorem" about such homeomorphisms when they are differentiable.

Comment: Thanks! Rotation number, Poincaré Classification and Denjoys Theorem (I accidentally wrote "Arnaud" in my post...) are the first part of the thesis. However I am trying to find something that explores some deeper connection, especially since the connection to Lie groups seems to be right there